# Dynamic cell size uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I get a json object with different text. I arrange the obtained pieces one by one with the following function `addText(content: number.content!, bottomAnchor: anchor!)`:

```
func addText(content: String, bottomAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor) -> NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {

    let shortContentPost: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = content
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: label.text!)
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 10
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
        label.attributedText = attributedString;

        return label
    }()
    contentView.addSubview(shortContentPost)
    shortContentPost.anchor(bottomAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 15, leftConstant: 15, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 15, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 100)

    return shortContentPost.bottomAnchor
}
```

Everything is output in UITableViewCell, but the automatic height can not be adjusted in any way.

Such a strange output route was chosen in order to get a grid like this. And a similar conclusion is used to combine in one cell text, pictures, links and other.

[image]

Previously, I implemented all this through the UICollectionView and calculated the height manually. The way worked, but there was a problem with inaccurate calculation of height and he had to refuse.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if(indexPath.item == 0){
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postId", for: indexPath) as! PostViewTableCell
        cell.contentArray = contentArray
        cell.homeController = self.navigationController
        return cell
    }
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

These are tableView functions

TableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class PostViewTableCell: UITableViewCell {
var anchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?
var contentArray: [PostContentModel]?{
    didSet{
        anchor = datePublishPost.bottomAnchor
        for number in contentArray! {
            if(number.switcher == 1) {
                anchor = addTextContent(content: number.content!, bottomAnchor: anchor!)
            }
            if(number.switcher == 2){
                anchor = addImageContent(content: number.content!, bottomAnchor: anchor!)
            }
            if(number.switcher == 3){
                anchor = addCaptionFirst(content: number.content!, bottomAnchor: anchor!)
            }
            if(number.switcher == 4){
                anchor = addButtonLink(content: number.content!, link: number.link!, bottomAnchor: anchor!)
            }
        }
    }
}

let authorImage: CustomImageView = {
    let image = CustomImageView()
    image.backgroundColor = .white
    image.image = UIImage(named: "authorImage")
    image.layer.masksToBounds = false
    image.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    image.clipsToBounds = true

    return image
}()

let authorNameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    label.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.51, green: 0.51, blue: 0.51, alpha: 1)

    return label
}()

let titlePost: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    return label
}()

let categoryPost: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.31, green: 0.31, blue: 0.31, alpha: 1)
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold)
    return label
}()

let datePublishPost: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel ()
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)
    label.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.52, green: 0.52, blue: 0.52, alpha: 1)
    return label
}()

var homeController: UINavigationController?
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupView()
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    let subviews = self.subviews
    for subview in subviews {
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}

func setupView(){
    addSubview(authorImage)
    addSubview(authorNameLabel)
    addSubview(titlePost)
    addSubview(categoryPost)
    addSubview(datePublishPost)
    authorImage.anchor(self.topAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 20, leftConstant: 15, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 30, heightConstant: 30)
    authorNameLabel.anchor(authorImage.topAnchor, left: authorImage.rightAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 5, leftConstant: 10, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
    titlePost.anchor(authorNameLabel.bottomAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 13, leftConstant: 15, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 15, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
    categoryPost.anchor(titlePost.bottomAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 7, leftConstant: 15, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
    datePublishPost.anchor(categoryPost.topAnchor, left: categoryPost.rightAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 15, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
}

func addTextContent(content: String, bottomAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor) -> NSLayoutYAxisAnchor{

    let shortContentPost: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = content
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: label.text!)
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 10
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
        label.attributedText = attributedString;

        return label
    }()

    contentView.addSubview(shortContentPost)
    shortContentPost.anchor(bottomAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 15, leftConstant: 15, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 15, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)

    return shortContentPost.bottomAnchor
}

func addImageContent(content: String, bottomAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor) -> NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    let image: CustomImageView = {
        let image = CustomImageView()
        image.image = UIImage(named: content)
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        image.clipsToBounds = true

        return image
    }()


    let imageURL = "https://brodude.ru/wp-content/uploads/" + content.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!
    image.loadImageUsingUrlString(urlString: imageURL)

    contentView.addSubview(image)
    image.anchor(bottomAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 15, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 250)

    return image.bottomAnchor
}

func addCaptionFirst(content: String, bottomAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor) -> NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    let Caption: UILabel = {
        let lb = UILabel()
        lb.text = content
        lb.numberOfLines = 0
        lb.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold)
        return lb
    }()

    contentView.addSubview(Caption)
    Caption.anchor(bottomAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 30, leftConstant: 15, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 15, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
    return Caption.bottomAnchor
}

func addButtonLink(content: String, link: String, bottomAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor) -> NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    let button: LinkButton = {
        let bt = LinkButton()
        bt.LinkString = link
        bt.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold)
        bt.setTitle(content, for: UIControlState.normal)
        bt.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        bt.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
        bt.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0.07, green: 0.32, blue: 0.89, alpha: 1.0), for: UIControlState.normal)
        bt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(linkOut), for: .touchUpInside)
        return bt
    }()
    button.sizeToFit()
    contentView.addSubview(button)
    button.anchor(bottomAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 20, leftConstant: 15, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 15, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
    return button.bottomAnchor
}

@objc func linkOut(sender: LinkButton!){
    let viewController: WebViewController = {
        let pv = WebViewController()
        pv.LinkString = sender.LinkString
        return pv
    }()
    homeController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Comment: return 50.0 in `estimatedHeightForRowAt ` delegate.

Comment: show your code for the cell layout and for the `cellForRowAt`

Comment: @MilanNosáľ added

Comment: if you have just 3 static cells, I don't think a `tableView` is really anyhow useful.. if you used a cell per every text paragraph, then it might be helpful performance wise, but in this case you could have simply used scrollView

Comment: show the rest of the uiTableViewCell code

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Already thought of the scrollView, but how to determine the height in this case? The content is dynamic, and scrollView requires a designated height? Or is it not?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Added

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Oh, God, thank you. Thanks to your advice, I tried to return to UIScrollView. And it turned out as necessary! I sat for two weeks on the grid problem in the post view. And here such a simple solution.

Comment: @Евгений leaving an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just 3 static cells, I don't think a `tableView` is really anyhow useful. `UITableView` is useful performance-wise if there are many cells that can be reused - then the UI does not have to create and hold the whole UI all the time, but just the visible portion of the `tableView`.

In your case, since all of the content is pushed into one cell, I would recommend simply using `UIScrollView`.

Or alternatively (in case of large content) use a `tableView` with a cell per paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

// You have to provide an estimated minimum height of cell.
i.e

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50.0
}
```

The cell can resize above this value.